# How to expand a div horizontally until it hits another div?

Tags: html, css

If I have two divs and one will change width each time the page is loaded (the page loads a different picture each time) how do I make the other one expand or de-expand so it hits the other div?

Problem solved so I took out the URL.

Comment: Do you want to do it dynamically using javascript or with css?

Comment: In my experience with ecommerce stores… You should make that image a fixed width. If it has a variable width, the text will jump left and right when navigating from one page to the next (disorienting).

Comment: Oh I didn't think of that... well I just took your advice and made the change and it looks good and I imagine the customers will not be disoriented. So I guess that makes this question moot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the HTML structure and CSS you would need:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="summary"></div>
</div>​

#wrapper
{
    padding: 30px;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background:#00FF00;    
}

#image
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:250px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
}

#summary
{
    width:auto;
    height:200px;
    background: #FF0000;    
}​
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rBwRq/) for you to play with. Adjust the width of the picture div and see how the summary div responds

Comment: That works perfect, but I decided to go another route as another user commented on the post. Although this does work so I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks :)